# String with EX, EEX, EXP or EE scientific notation to double

Tags: java, scientific-notation

In my code I am receiving numeric values as strings from different sources. One of the source is sending me this kind of value:

> -6.535402781EX-05

After few tests I know that **EX** format is not handled by `Double.valueOf()` method. `NumberFormatException` is thrown.

I figured out easy workaround:

```
 String val = "-6.535402781EX-05".replace("X", "");
```

Actually it is working, but I am not sure if that's best solution.  I saw also **EEX**, **EE** and **EXP**. Question: How to protect my code for this kind of edge cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `replaceAll` witha regex instead of `replace` if those are the only possible values:

```
String[] val  = {"-6.535402781EX-05","-6.535402781EEX-05","-6.535402781EE-05","-6.535402781EXP-05"};
for(String v :val){
    System.out.println(v.replaceAll("[EXP]{2,}", "E"));
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be easier than @david 's one. I like the regex, which is minimal in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would a simple regular expression do the trick for you? You could first convert the different input formats to your known input format that can be handled by `Double.valueOf()`.

```
String pattern = "(\\D?)(\\d+)(\\.?)(\\d+)(\\D+)(\\d+)";

List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("-6.535402781EX-05", 
                                    "-6.535402781EXP-05", 
                                    "-6.535402781EE-05", 
                                    "-6.535402781E-05", 
                                    "6.535402781E-05",
                                    "6.535402781",
                                    "-6.535402781",
                                    "6.5",
                                    "6");

inputs.forEach((String in) -> System.out.println(in.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2$3$4E-$6")));
```

The inputs in my example should be converted to the following and parsing them should be possible with `Double.valueOf()`.

```
-6.535402781E-05
-6.535402781E-05
-6.535402781E-05
-6.535402781E-05
6.535402781E-05
6.535402781
-6.535402781
6.5
6
```

You should be careful to add enough unit test cases for all input formats you want to support.